# Stream API. Каким образом преобразовать values для Map в одном stream?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, коллекции

Пытаюсь, используя стримы, получить Map вида HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>(при этом получая Map вида HashMap<Integer, List<int[]>>) из Collection<int[]>. Код следующий:

```
 final int[][] OFFSETS = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}};

 Map<Integer, int[]> coordinates = new HashMap<>();
 Map<int[], Integer> coordinates_inverse = new HashMap<>();
 int[][] tmp = new int[64][2];
 int k = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
   for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
       int[] member = new int[]{i, j};
       tmp[k] = member;
       coordinates.put(k, tmp[k]);
       coordinates_inverse.put(tmp[k], k);
       k++;
    }
  }

 Map<Integer, List<int[]>> test = coordinates.values().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> coordinates_inverse.get(c), c -> Arrays.stream(OFFSETS)
                    .map(i -> i = new int[]{i[0] + c[0], i[1] + c[1]})
                    .filter(i -> i[0] > 0 && i[0] < 9 && i[1] > 0 && i[1] < 9)
                    .sorted((i, j) -> {
                        if (i[0] == j[0]) return i[1] - j[1];
                        else return i[0] - j[0];
                    })
                   // .map(i-> Arrays.stream(i).map(coordinates_inverse::get).boxed())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));

 for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<int[]>> e: test.entrySet()){
        System.out.printf("Изначальная позиция " + e.getKey() + "\n" + "Ходы " + Arrays.deepToString(e.getValue().toArray()) + "\n");
    }
```

Данный код при компиляции выдает карту ключей со значениями, все элементы которых содержат null, хотя должны содержать типы Integer.

Есть ли альтернативные способы заполнения значениями Map или есть возможность выполнения всех преобразований в одном стриме?

Comment: Лично я не понял, какой результат вы хотите? final int[][] OFFSETS = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}}; - это вы имеете на входе. На выходе должен быть Map, насколько я понял. Какой именно? Какие значения там должны быть?

Comment: Поправил код (закомментировал одну строчку). В результате хотел получить Map вида Map<Integer, List<Integer>> в одном стриме, но компилятор ругается на тип. Из текущего стрима получаю Map вида Map<Integer, List<int[]>>, в котором мне нужно преобразовать все значения вида List<int[]> на List<Integer> с помощью coordinates_inverse поэлементно. Тогда возникает вопрос - можно ли сделать всё в одном стриме, либо нужно затем запускать отдельный стрим или использовать другие библиотеки (типа гуава) для преобразования значений Map?

Comment: Стрим вызывается у конкретного объекта. Например, у коллекции, массива и.т.д. Соответственно, все необходимые операции над этим объектом можно сделать в одном стриме. Если же нужны операции над другим объектом, то нужен второй стрим. Вопрос требует уточнение, поскольку нерабочий и некомпилируемый код не может описать конечной задачи. Угадывать это нет никакого желания. Посему возвращаемся назад - какой результат должен быть в результате обработки указанного массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После некоторых манипуляций получилось получить нужную Map. Если кому интересно, привожу код (ошибка для меня остаётся пока неясной - проблема решилась при использовании структуры TreeMap и задании нового Comparator, поскольку не отрабатывалась функция get для структуры HashMap coordinates_inverse):

```
 final int[][] OFFSETS = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}};

 Map<Integer, int[]> coordinates = new TreeMap<>();
 Map<int[], Integer> coordinatesInverse = new TreeMap<>((i, j) -> {
        if (i[0] == j[0]) return i[1] - j[1];
        else return i[0] - j[0];
 });
 int[][] tmp = new int[64][2];
 int k = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
         int[] member = new int[]{i, j};
         tmp[k] = member;
         coordinates.put(k, tmp[k]);
         coordinatesInverse.put(tmp[k], k);
         k++;
     }
 }

 Map<Integer, List<Integer>> test = coordinates.values().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(coordinatesInverse::get, c -> Arrays.stream(OFFSETS)
                    .map(i -> i = new int[]{i[0] + c[0], i[1] + c[1]})
                    .filter(i -> i[0] > 0 && i[0] < 9 && i[1] > 0 && i[1] < 9)
                    .map(coordinatesInverse::get)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));

 for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> e: test.entrySet()){
        System.out.printf("Изначальная позиция " + e.getKey() + "\n" + "Ходы " + Arrays.deepToString(e.getValue().toArray()) + "\n");
    }
```

Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся!